# Let $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in A_6$ be permutations with cycle-type $(2, 4)$. Show there exists $\tau \in A_6: \tau \tau_1 \tau^{-1} = \tau_2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

> Let $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in A_6$ be permutations with cycle-type $(2, 4)$. Show there exists $$\tau \in A_6\mid \tau \tau_1 \tau^{-1} = \tau_2$$

I know $\tau_1 = (a b c d)(e f)$ and $\tau_2 = (a^{'}b^{'}c^{'}d^{'})(e^{'}f^{'})$ and I've proved that these lies in $A_6$.

I know we can write $\tau (a b c d)(e f) \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a) \tau(b) \tau(c) \tau(d))(\tau(e) \tau(f))$ and I know there exists $\tau \in S_6$ satisfying $\tau \tau_1 \tau^{-1} = \tau_2$, but how do I determine if it lies in $A_6$ without knowing the form of this permutation ?

Note: $A_6$ denote the alternating group of $S_6$ determined by the $sgn$ homomorphism.

Comment: Small hint: Can you think of just one $\tau\in S_6$ or can you find more? If so, what can you say about their product?

Comment: I can think of many $\tau \in S_6$. What exactly do you mean ? :)

Comment: Well, I was referring to $\tau$ satisfying $\tau\tau_1\tau^{-1}=\tau_2$. As you mentioned, $\tau*(abcd)(ef)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(a)\tau(b)\tau(c)\tau(d))(\tau(e)\tau(f))$, so **the** $\tau$ with $\tau(a)=a', ..., \tau(f)=f'$ is an obvious candidate for a $\tau\in S_6$ with the above property. My question now just is whether you can come up with another candidate (say $\tilde\tau$) with that property.

Comment: I know I have to come up with something involving a proper cycle product that under the $sgn$ homomorphism yield 1. But I don't see how to build this from two-cycles or three-cycles.

Comment: Could you give a hint more ?

Comment: Apaprently cycle type $\;2\le 4\;$ means simply type $\;(2,4)=\;$ the product of two disjoint cycles: one a transposition and one a 4-cycle. Why the $\;\le\;$ symbol?

Comment: This is the notation of my textbook. It says a cycle type 1,1,1,1,1,1 with $\le$ instead of ,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your permutations are $\tau_1 = (a\ b)(c\ d\ e\ f),$ and $\tau_2 = (x\ y)(z\ w\ u\ v),$ then $\tau$ should map $a$ to $x,$ $b$ to $y,$ $c$ to $z$ and so on.

**EDIT** I missed the $A_6$ part, but the point is that if $\tau,$ as above is not in $A_6,$ map $b$ to $x$ and $a$ to $y$ (and everything else as before) instead.

Comment: Indeed, but can you tell me why $\tau \in A_6$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen ah, yes. Actually, what you do is check whether it is in $A_6,$ and if not, you compose it with the transposition which exchanges $a$ and $b.$

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen see the edit.

Comment: so your point is: if $\tau \notin A_6$ then we write $(x y)\tau$, which implies this permutation is even and lies in $A_6$. And $\tau \tau_1 \tau^{-1} = \tau_2$ now the only change in regards to $\tau$ is we get $(y x)(z w u v) = (x y)(z w u v)$ ? Thank you so much.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yup, precisely!